# How to build Antlr4 C# grammar using Eclipse?

Tags: c#, grammar, antlr4

I am trying to build the Antlr V4 grammars available in the following repository: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4. I have successfully build Python3 and Java grammars and targeted *.java files have successfully been generated. But, when I have tried to build C# grammar, e.g. CSharpLexer.g4, CSharpParser.g4 and CsharpPreporcessorParser.g4 I am getting build error. It generates following error:

```
error(114): CSharpPreprocessorParser.g4:7:21: cannot find tokens file ./CSharpLexer.tokens
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:20:62: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '.'
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:25:14: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '?'
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:25:37: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '*'
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:31:8: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '*'
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:71:3: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '<'
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:71:14: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: ','
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:71:25: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '>'
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:76:14: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: ','
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:80:15: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: ':'
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:99:3: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '='
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:99:9: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '+='
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:99:16: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '-='
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:99:23: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '*='
error(126): CSharpParser.g4:99:30: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '/='
```

I am trying to build this using Antlr V4 eclipse plugin. My target is to generate *.java files to proceed with next steps. Not sure how to build all the csharp *.g4 files altogether as Java and Python have only one grammar file respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build CSharpLexer.g4 first. Then build CSharpParser.g4 and CsharpPreporcessorParser.g4. Building CSharpLexer.g4 will generate CSharpLexer.tokens that is used by later stages of CSharpParser.g4.